# Union tables stored in variables returned from Oracle function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using following script to call an Oracle function which returns table, which is working fine:

```
declare 
        result number;
        today VARCHAR(10):= TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD');
begin
         result := func(today);
end;
```

But now I want to get last 3 days of data too, so I am changing my script to following:

```
declare 
    result number;
    result1 number;
    result2 number;
    result_final number;
    today VARCHAR(10):= TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD');
    today_1 VARCHAR(10):= TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - 1, 'YYYYMMDD');
    today_2 VARCHAR(10):= TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - 2, 'YYYYMMDD');
begin
     result := func(today);
     result1 := func(today_1);
     result2 := funct(today_2);
     result_final := union(result, result1, result2);
end;
```

However, above script is throwing error. I tried couple of more different syntax but no luck. Can anyone help me with correct syntax please, so that last 3 days of data can be stored in single variable?

I didn't write the function body but when I asked for it they sent me following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FILLTABLE (SHIPMENTDATE IN VARCHAR2)
IS 
l_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
TRAILER_ID VARCHAR2(100);
WAREHOUSE_CODE VARCHAR2(100);
ACTUAL_DATE DATE;
OK NUMERIC;
BEGIN
l_cursor := EUROWMS.DATAIKUEXTRACT$B.GETTRAILERSSHIPPED (TO_DATE(SHIPMENTDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
LOOP 
    FETCH l_cursor
    INTO  TRAILER_ID , WAREHOUSE_CODE, ACTUAL_DATE;
    EXIT WHEN l_cursor%NOTFOUND;
        OK := EUROWMS.DATAIKUEXTRACT$B.GETSHIPMENTDATA(TRAILER_ID,WAREHOUSE_CODE );
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE l_cursor;
END;
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: `result number` is a scalar variable, so the function cannot return a table. You may also return the value without any PL/SQL code, but in plain SQL. Just union three `select func(...) from dual`

Comment: Hi @astentx thanks for the response. But result variable is returning a table, which I am successfully achieving in first script. Only problem is I can not union tables stored in different variables

Comment: Thanks @astentx but select func(...) from dual statement also throwing error :(

Comment: Please, post the function delcaration (only the code between `create function` and `as`). You cannot collect tabular data into variable of type `number`

Comment: @astentx edited in question

Comment: There's no any function in your code, but procedure. And that procedure doesn't return anything, so the question is unclear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235822/discussion-between-pardeep-naik-and-astentx).